# phpmyadmin : Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported

Tags: permissions, firefox, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

I'm trying to use phpmyadmin to install a website locally (already downloaded it, now I need to set the database).
I have installed xampp (lampp) and everything seemed to work fine.
But when I try to "Go to aplication" to open phpmyadmin to create the database, I get:

> Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.
> ($XAUTHORITY is /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority which is owned by Lau.)
> Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.
> ($XAUTHORITY is /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority which is owned by Lau.)
> Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.
> ($XAUTHORITY is /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority which is owned by Lau.)
> /usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: iceweasel: not 
>  /usr/bin/xdg-open: 869:
> seamonkey: not found
>  /usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: mozilla: not found
> /usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: epiphany: not found
>  /usr/bin/xdg-open: 869:
> konqueror: not found 
> /usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: chromium: not found
> /usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: chromium-browser: not found
>  /usr/bin/xdg-open:
> 869: google-chrome: not found
>  /usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: www-browser: not
> found 
> /usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: links2: not found 
> /usr/bin/xdg-open:
> 869: elinks: not found 
> /usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: links: not found
> /usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: lynx: not found
>  /usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: w3m:
> not found 
> xdg-open: no method available for opening
> 'http://localhost:80'

I'm pretty new to all this. Can anyone help me? I don't want to be using Firefox as root.
BTW I'm using Ubuntu 20.

Thanks!

Lau

Comment: Try to log as different user then (not root) . Or do not use sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Just start Firefox as your regular user and got to `http://localhost:80` as indicated in the last line of the message you quoted.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. I keep getting the same message.

Comment: So you are still trying to start Firefox while being root. Try to start it from a user who is not root.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Isn't "root" the only root user? I'm logged in using my user that I created when I installed Ubuntu. Is this a root user? How can I change that? Because I need sudo privilege to use Xampp, It's one of the requirements. But I understand having sudo privileges is not the same as being root, right? 
Sorry, I'm quite new to all this...

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "having sudo privileges"? **Being able to use** sudo or **actually using it**? Being able to use sudo is not equal to being root. Actually using sudo is equal to being root. So if you are starting Firefox using sudo, don't do it. Just start it as your regular user you are logged in, by clicking on Firefox icon.